# How to remove namespace from the soap message received from server

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I am very new to [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and I am stuck with the issue of removing namespace from the SOAP message that I receive from the external server (I am serving as a client for consuming the service)

The stubs that are generated from the wsdl have a different namespace in the @WebResult while the SOAP envelope which is received from the server system is different.
I want to apply a generic solution so as to remove the namespace from the response message so the client validation does not fail.

> o.a.c.p.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://www.abc.xyz/webservices/facade}service#{http://www.abc.xyz/webservices/facade}serviceName has thrown exception, unwinding now
>
> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected element {http://www.abc.xyz/webservices/facade}serviceResponse found.   Expected {http:// www.abc.xyz/webservices/facade/**xxx**}serviceResponse.

Kindly help.

Solutions tried till  now :

(CXF Transformation Feature)

```
Map<String, String> inTransformMap = Collections.singletonMap("{http:// www.abc.xyz/webservices/facade/**xxx**}serviceResponse", "");
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.transform.TransformInInterceptor transformInInterceptor = new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.transform.TransformInInterceptor();
transformInInterceptor.setInTransformElements(inTransformMap);
proxy.getInInterceptors().add(transformInInterceptor);
```

In this approach, when I try to replace `{http://www.abc.xyz/webservices/facade/**xxx**}serviceResponse` with `""`, server hangs and it goes into infinite loop at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.transform.InTransformReader.handleDeepDrop() line 266

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this issue by the following

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
Map<String, Object> props = factory.getProperties();
if (null == props) {
    props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
props.put("soap.no.validate.parts", true);
factory.setProperties(props);
```

The above solution will allow the incoming response validation to be turned off and hence there won't be any exception like org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected element.